# Counting Columns Horizontally

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a view that has 200 columns of data in a pivot table horizontally. I want to COUNT() or SUM() across those 200 columns. How can I accomplish this without writing a huge SQL query where I have to write every column out?

How I Imagined:

```
COUNT( [Column 1] -> [Column 200]) // Counts all values in Column 1 through Column 200.
```

How It Is Really:

```
COUNT([Column 1]) +  COUNT([Column 2 ]) +  COUNT([Column 3])... AS 'Total'
```

Note:

I'm inserting this count into another query where I'm grouping by another column name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to count the columns that have any values on a row without explicitely writing every column, then you *could* use `XML PATH` (though it assumes the same data type for each column, and I'm not really sure about performance on your dataset):

```
SELECT T2.X.value('count(*/text())', 'int') as ColumnCount 
FROM YourTable AS T1 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT T1.* 
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS T2(X)
```

Comment: The `SUM()` version of this will ignore any fields with characters in them, but if you have any fields that hold integers that you don't want added (like `ID`) you can cancel them out by using a subquery: `FROM (SELECT ID*-1 'NegID',*
   FROM #Table1
   ) AS T1 `  for example.

Comment: I don't have the same data type in each column unfortunately. I assume that's why this method is not working as I have a date/timestamp in the data set that is not converting. I could always put the 200 columns into a separate view with a primary key though and just union them together.

Comment: @Fastidious Actually, this should work for datetime and chars. Can you create a sample dataset on sqlfiddle?

Comment: I can't at the moment, but I will check into it later. Creating a sample data set would be easy though. You can create a set of records with 12 columns. The first column is the Date. The second column is the Master Type of that record where the 10 columns have values ranging from Type A to Type z. Group by Master Type. I want to count how many Types of the Master Type is in the record based on a date range. Example Record : 01/01/2013 (Date) | Type C (Master) | Type A (10 Other Columns) | Type E | Type C | NULL | NULL | NULL. Example Result: Type C (Master) | 3

Comment: Got this to work. Sorry for late response. I also found a better way to roll up and count these data. Before I use a pivot table, I just went ahead and rolled up the data into a separate view and query both views for the final result as opposed to trying to do everything in one swing.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to write every column out.

The easiest way is to get the list of columns and either use SQL or Excel to make the expression you want.  Here is an example:

```
select '['+Column_Name+'] +'
from Information_Schema.columns c
where table_name = @YourTableName
```

You can then copy the code into SSMS or whatever your query interface is.  Note:  remove the final `+` so it is syntactically correct.